# Insert value in postgres with type PATH

Tags: postgresql, coordinates

I have created a table with a column type PATH as above (following the PostgreSQL documentation)

```
CREATE TABLE public.geometry_polyline_volume
(
    id          serial not null primary key,
    distance    float not null,
    height      float not null,
    coordinates path not null
);
```

Trying to insert the above values as a row

```
INSERT INTO public.geometry_polyline_volume(id, distance, height, coordinates)
VALUES (2,  500, 0, path((15.878137629895164,47.08306448089695), (15.56169808311181,47.219041634920686), (15.267442604782124,47.4201665137259), (15.092631384557304,47.71366328136526), (15.234428926980286,47.95865145177352)));
```

I am taking the following error

> Message    : ERROR: column "coordinates" is of type path but
> expression is of type record

Comment: I don't believe that text "path" is supposed to be included in VALUES https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-geometric.html.

Comment: Removed it and the message remains the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert it into text, like the following :

```sql
INSERT INTO public.geometry_polyline_volume(id, distance, height, coordinates)
VALUES (
  2,
  500,
  0,
  path(
    '(15.878137629895164,47.08306448089695),
     (15.56169808311181,47.219041634920686),
     (15.267442604782124,47.4201665137259),
     (15.092631384557304,47.71366328136526),
     (15.234428926980286,47.95865145177352)'
  )
);
```

Comment: Strange but it works! thank you!
Post your answer also at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60072610/insert-value-in-postgres-with-type-path/60072856#60072856

Comment: @chatzich: answer yourself for stackoverflow, link it the answer here if you want.

Comment: I have done it already

Comment: More examples about the right syntax for PostgeSQL native geometry types in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-geometry.html